# s3 uploading file post request

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file via a post request to amazon s3. Trouble is I don't know how to format the request to be a multipart form.

This is what I have right now:

```
content_type = "image/JPEG"
key = 'uploads/filename.jpg'
acl = "public-read"
bucket = None

params_raw = create_upload_data(content_type,key,acl,bucket)

params = { 'policy': params_raw['policy'],'acl':acl,'signature':params_raw['signature'],'key':params_raw['key'],'Content-Type':params_raw['Content-Type'],'AWSAccessKeyId':params_raw['AWSAccessKeyId'],'success_action_status':params_raw['success_action_status'],'binary': binary_data}
r = requests.post(params_raw['form_action'],data=params)
```

I think I am getting a bad response because it isn't a multipart form but here is what the response text looks like:

```
{"request": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Conflicting query string parameters: acl, policy</Message><ArgumentName>ResourceType</ArgumentName><ArgumentValue>acl</ArgumentValue><RequestId>D558E016151E448F</RequestId><HostId>WT5aT0OOqJx3ziPgYFzjuTHJSERaCcuJG+y/acs6+l/mWVwO0MiH3lhWyBWIdhKr9BnhdIpkarw=</HostId></Error>"}
```

How do I structure the request with the file... it is a .jpg in base 64?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sufficient to change content-type

```
content-type =  'multipart/form-data'
```

Comment: did the request like this and it works!     r = requests.post(params_raw['form_action'],data=params,files=dict(foo='bar'))

Answer (score 0):

Had a fair bit of pain around this but finally got it going. Very simple in the end!

```
url = "https://yourbucket.s3.amazonaws.com"

#complete_path is the local server path to the file
files = {'file':open(complete_path,'rb')}

r = requests.post(url, data=params, files=files)
```